# Как закрыть меню Bootstrap при нажатии на ссылку?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Доброго времени суток!
Имеется меню Bootstrap.
Нужен скрипт который будет закрывать меню Bootstrap и возвращать обратный цвет background кнопки до её нажатия при нажатии на любой пункт меню, заранее спасибо за помощь!

```
<!-- Меню сайта -->
    <div id="menu">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
            <div id="menu-text">
                <a href="#head" data-target="anchor" class="navbar-brand visible-xs" ><p>Reco меню</p></a>
            </div>
            <div id="menu-height">
                <a href="#head" data-target="anchor" class="navbar-brand hidden-xs"><p></p></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#benefits-h1" data-target="anchor"><p>НАШИ<br>ПРЕИМУЩЕСТВА</p></a></li>
                <li><a href="#myft" data-target="anchor"><p>МУФТЫ</p></a></li>
                <li><a href="#prais-contact" data-target="anchor"><p>ПРАЙС-ЛИСТ<br>КОНТАКТЫ</p></a></li>
                <li><a href="#foto-slide" data-target="anchor"><p>ФОТО И<br>ВИДЕО</p></a></li>
                <li><a href="#sertificat" data-target="anchor"><p>СЕРТИФИКАТЫ<br>КАЧЕСТВА</p></a></li>
                <li><a href="#stanok" data-target="anchor"><p>РЕЗЬБОНАКАТНЫЙ<br>СТАНОК RECO-40C</p></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: А почему вы не хотите использовать родной код бутстрапа?

Comment: В каком смысле? У меня есть лейдинг и на нём fixed меню, на мобиле если нажать на ссылку, меню скролится до якоря, но при этом не закрывается, что в итоге создаёт неудобство для пользователя

Comment: Если я вас верно понял, то вы используете фреймворк bootstrap для верстки. Вы подключили из него файл bootstrap.js (bootstrap.min.js)? Он обеспечивает необходимый вам функционал "из коробки", пример смотрите тут: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/#

Comment: Поймите, у меня не по страничная навигация, а по якорная

Comment: Обратите внимание, как там срабатывает меню в разделе Dropdown -  там именно что якорь (правда, пустой), и при нажатии на пункты меню там меню после этого закрывается.

Comment: Зайдите с мобилы и сами всё увидите, если нажимаете на любой пункт меню, в том числе на Dropdown, то меню не скрывается!

Comment: Я написал этот скрипт, но он не срабатывает 

<script> 
            $('.anchor').on('click', function () {
                $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
                $a = $($(this).attr('href'));  
                return false;
            });
        </script>

Answer (score 1):

```
   <script> 
        $('a[data-target^="anchor"]').on('click', function () {
            $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
            $a = $($(this).attr('href'));  
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря этому скрипту всё заработало!

```
<script> 
        $('a[data-target^="anchor"]').on('click', function () {
            $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
            $a = $($(this).attr('href'));  
            return false;
        });
</script>
```